# C++ STL vector of vectors and memory management

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, vector, memory-leaks

We have a scenario where we need to create an

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> data;
```

because the vectors aren't at all the same length.

When data gets freed, does every vector inside data also free up its space?

Comment: Yes.  When a `std::vector` is destructed, it calls the destructor of each of its elements.

Comment: Does it seem sensible to you that code like that would *not* work and somehow introduce a bug? What kind of standard library would include such data structures? What would you think should be expected of you to "fix" this?

Comment: @KerrekSB: The C Standard would, `float** array; ... free(array);` does not call free on the pointers contained in `array`.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: That's a stretched comparison - a pointer doesn't own anything. It's not the `float ** array;` that necessitates cleanup; it's whatever you do to obtain the value that you store in `array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the standard library types implement RAII appropriately. That is, any kind of internal dynamic allocation that they perform will be cleaned up automatically by the time the object is destroyed. You never need to worry about it.

In the case of the standard containers, like `std::vector`, it will automatically ensure that each of its elements is destroyed. Of course, if the elements of the `std::vector` are themselves `std::vector`s, they will in turn destroy their elements. Everything is automatic.

You may have seen examples in which you have a `std::vector<T*>` and the `T` objects were then allocated manually using `new`. It's important to realise here that the elements of the vector are not the `T` objects, but `T*` objects. The *pointers* will be cleaned up automatically. Since you manually allocated the `T` objects, you need to manually deallocate them. (As @Veritas says in the comments, in this case you should prefer using smart pointers)

Comment: Good answer. For completeness' sake, I would add that in those cases it's a good practice to use smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes
Whenever The "Scope" of 'data' ends , The destructor will be automatically called and memory that was allocated for'data' will be freed.
Whenever the destructor is called for a vector then the destructor each of its elements will be called.

Suppose for vector a(5)
Here destructors of a[0],a[1],... will be called.

Similarly in the above case vector< vector > x;
destructors of x[0],x[1] will be called consecutively..

But here each element x[i] is again a vector so again destructors of x[i][0],x[i][1]... will be called..

In this way all elements are destroyed Recursively..

Comment: The asker wants to know about the memory allocated for the elements of the internal `vector`s.

Comment: Scope is the wrong word, even in quotes. You mean *lifetime*. Confusing scope and lifetimes is in my experience a huge roadblock to understanding memory management and pointers.